# Pass cookies to WKWebView / SFSafariViewController?

Tags: swift, cookies, webview, alamofire, sfsafariviewcontroller

I'm using Alamofire for server access and the server API is using cookies for authentication. Now I would like to open a web view and include the auth cookie from the app in the web view.

The API and the URL in the web view is using the same domain. 
I don't really care if it's using WKWebView or SFSafariViewController, but I would prefer SFSafariViewController.

Is this possible?

Comment: You have to sync your cookies after changing from Httpcookiestorage to httpcookiestore for wkwebview. wkwebview has own cookie storage

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set cookies only using WKWebView. Read this first https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/97194